# Mysql tmpdir is out of space during large index creation

Tags: mysql, indexing, varchar

I am trying to index a varchar(255) column of a table with 2 billion rows. The indexation stops with the below error:

```
Error number 28 means ‘No space left on device
```

[This post](https://www.percona.com/blog/2020/02/25/mysql-error-1034-incorrect-key-file-on-innodb-table/) suggests I can just change the `tmpdir` to another partition with larger disk space.

Is this advised? Are there any downsides to doing so? (slower indexation ... etc)

**If not what are the detailed steps I need to go through to change `tmpdir` of mysql effectively?**

Answer (score 0):

Advised:  Yes.  Easy: yes.

In the old days, disk drives were small. Often a machine would have multiple drives to make it possible to store lots of data.  And file systems had limitations.  (Long ago, FAT16 on DOS topped out at 2 billion *bytes*, no way for it to hold 2 billion *rows*.)

So, having a setting for `tmpdir` made it easy to chop up the disk usage.  In rare cases, it can be beneficial to performance to do such separation, but even that is vanishing with the advent of SSDs.  Meanwhile, for really huge datasets, RAID striping provides a better way to provide performance than manually splitting up disk allocation.

Find the `my.cnf` configuration file.  In the `[mysqld]` section, add

```
tmpdir = /.../...
```

to point to some otherwise unused directory on a disk with lots of free space.

Meanwhile...  "2 billion rows" is large enough to lead to numerous challenges.  You may want to start a question in dba.stackexhange.com to discuss potential issues.

**innodb_tmpdir**

From the changelog for 5.6.29 and 5.7.11 (Feb 2016), `innodb_tmpdir` may be a better thing to change:

> A new InnoDB configuration option, innodb_tmpdir, allows you to configure a separate directory for temporary files created during online ALTER TABLE operations that rebuild the table. This option was introduced to help avoid MySQL temporary directory overflows that could occur as a result of large temporary files created during online ALTER TABLE operations. innodb_tmpdir can be configured dynamically using a SET statement.

> Online ALTER TABLE operations that rebuild a table also create an intermediate table file in the same directory as the original table. The innodb_tmpdir option is not applicable to intermediate table files. (Bug #19183565)

Comment: tmpdir is read only in my case as a quick fix I put the new directory in `innodb_tmpdir` which should work. The problem is that now the index creation immediately crashes with ERROR 1041 (HY000): Out of memory. It does not even start indexing. why is that?

Comment: @user7331538 - Something subtle is missing.  Can you provide `df` (from OS), `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  The SQL that is adding the index.

Comment: I assume the table is Engine=InnoDB?